# Have no clue, how to use OutputStream to print Float values

Tags: java, android

I have a variable that indicates me when my Socket is connected, so now I need to print my Accelerometers values through a OutputStream.

Comment: "Print" means text, while `OutputStream` is bytes. If you want to write text to an `OutputStream`, you should wrap it with an `OutputStreamWriter`, which should be wrapped with a `BufferedWriter`, and you probably want that wrapped with a `PrintWriter` for easy-to-use `print()` methods.

Comment: And the easiest `OutputStream` to test on is `System.out` -> Console.

Comment: Did you do any research? What same up and what are you still missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientSocket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
out = new PrintWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
out.println(printurstuff);
```